# What is the name of the screen that appears when the computer starts?

Tags: boot, bios

When our PC starts the company logo appears such as “SONY,” “DELL” etc… Just like the boot loaders, BIOS menu does this screen have a name?

Comment: this is the OEM Logo which is stored in the BIOS. I don't know a special name of it. Look for OEM Logo settings in the BIOS if you want to disable it.

Comment: I don't know the name of the screen itself, but some BIOS activate it with the option "quiet boot", if enabled it replaces the BIOS post screen for an image, others call it the option "hide post screen" that is essentially the same thing.

Comment: there is a related [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootsplash)

Answer (score 1):

It is generally referred to as a “BIOS Logo” or a “BIOS Boot Logo”. A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Bios%20Boot%20logo&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) shows tons of examples of how to change and adjust the logo as well as examples of BIOS boot logos from many different system.s

Comment: Well, a "simple" search if you already know the name. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the Screen in splash screen

Comment: That was my initial reaction; then "bootsplash", which applies specifically to the boot.  However, all of those are associated with the software (or OS) that loads it.  The question is about the manufacturer logo that appears before anything is loaded (and on a dual boot, appears regardless of the OS that is selected).

Answer (score 0):

As I recall its name is "BIOS splashscreen logo".